# Defer execution of page controller until init data is gathered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an SPA. I have some basic init data that I'm fetching from the server that I'm certain that I want to defer every page load until that data is loaded. (this data contains whether the user is logged in, permissions, and other vital stuff). So if I have a service for fetching and accessing that data, a page controller might start execution before I have the data, which is bad.

I can't use a promise either, partly because it doesn't solve my problem that I don't want the page to begin loading, and partly because it can't be updated easily and I don't want to always use a promise to fetch this basic data

this is what i've tried so far:

my service

```
app.factory('AppData', function($q, $http){

    var appData = {};

    $http
        .post( "/api/GeneralActions/getInitData", {
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            appData = data;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        });

    return {
        getAppData: function () {
            return appData;
        }
    };
});
```

my page controller:

```
app.controller('MainPreferences', function($scope, AppData){

    // when this gets executed, appData is null
    $scope.appData = AppData.getAppData();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following snippet

```
app.factory('AppData', function($q, $http){

    var appData = {};

    $http
        .post( "/api/GeneralActions/getInitData", {
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //appData = data;
            angular.extend(appData, data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        });

    return {
        getAppData: function () {
            return appData;
        }
    };
});
```

Instead creating appData object again, just extend it with data . By this way your appData object pointer will not change and controllers will also get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `ngRoute`? If so, it sounds like what you want is to have a resolve property on your routes to require them to load something before changing the path to the new route.

See [the ngRoute docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) and search for `resolve`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the stock Angular `ngRoute` routing system, you can use [the `resolve` property on the route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) to specify a map of promise-returning functions. The route controller will not be initialized before these promises are all resolved, and as a bonus, the promises' results are injected into the route controller.

For example:

```
$routeProvider.when('/foo', {
  controller: 'fooCtrl',
  resolve: {
    bar: function($http) { return $http.get('/load/the/bar'); }
  }
});

// bar is injected from the route resolve
myApp.controller('fooCtrl', function($scope, bar) {
  $scope.bar = bar;
});
```

Comment: as he said, he do not wants to call this api everytime.

Comment: But this app data is for all routes... I don't want to repeat it for all of them

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
app.factory('AppData', function($q, $http){

    var appData = {};

    return {
        getAppData: function () {
            $http.post( "/api/GeneralActions/getInitData", {}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    return data;
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            });
        }
    };     
});
```